# ASP.NET 5: Error with Nuget package in Class library Package

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I start playing with VS2015 community version and ASP.NET 5.

I have added a new class library (Package) as a new project into my solution but am unable to install a NuGet package in it. After the restoring, I have a "Reference (Errors - see Error List)".

If i add a basic Library Class (.dll) as a new project into my solution and try to install the same NuGet package, it works beautifully as it used to.

Perhaps, I am misunderstanding how this new class library package works and I am trying to misuse it...

Thanks for your help.

--------------------------------------------------------------EDIT 1-----------------------------------------------------------
Project.json: The warning flag in that case is on the EF package:
[image: Class Libary package with error on EF]

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "testFinal Class Library",
    "authors": [ "SylvainC" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet": { }
    }
}
```

----------------------------------------------------EDIT 1 bis after update to beta8--------------------------

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ClassLibrary5 Class Library",
  "authors": [ "SylvainC" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
  }
}
```

--------------------------------------------------------------EDIT 2-----------------------------------------------------------

After upgrading the dnvm (dvnm upgrade), i was able to run the "dnu restore" command but got the following error:

```
>dnu restore
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-beta8-15858

  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/
Restoring packages for D:\testFinal\project.json
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Reflection'
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Reflection'
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Globalization'
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Globalization'
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Globalization
  An error occurred while sending the request.
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Globalization
  An error occurred while sending the request.
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Reflection
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Globalization'
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Reflection'
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Globalization'
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Reflection
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Reflection'
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework
  An error occurred while sending the request.
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Reflection
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Reflection'
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Globalization
  An error occurred while sending the request.
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Globalization
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Globalization'
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Globalization'
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Reflection
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Reflection'
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'
Error: FindPackagesById: System.Reflection
  An error occurred while sending the request.
----------
Error: FindPackagesById: System.Globalization
  An error occurred while sending the request.
Error: FindPackagesById: System.Globalization
  An error occurred while sending the request.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

---------------------------------------------EDIT 3 with final error and feeds------------------------------

```
Restore failed
An error occurred while sending the request.
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\sylvainc\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
Feeds used:
    https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
    https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/
```

Sylvain

Comment: Can you please share the project.json file?

Comment: Right click on references and select  restore packages. What is shown in the output window?

Comment: I've had the same issue and resolved it by running ```dnu restore``` from command line.

Comment: Thanks @andrej. I have run the dnu restore but still got an error. I have edited my post accordingly

Comment: Thanks @VictorHurdugaci, I have edited my post and added the project.json

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a proxy issue giving me this `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888` error.

Tracking it down with Fiddler, I discovered that after opening Fiddler, the restore process and adding new Nuget packages was working fine. A situation quite similar to this post [Why calling API in ASP.NET works only if I have Fiddler open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561064/why-calling-api-in-asp-net-works-only-if-i-have-fiddler-open) or here: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-.

I also tried to create a dnx.exe.config into `C:\Users\sylvainc\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin` as suggested in http://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/451.
Unfortunately it seems not to work with the beta8 version.

My first workaround solution was to use the HTTP protocol to access my NuGet packages as suggested here: [Visual Studio 2015 - Can't sign in, Use NuGet, etc. behind corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571224/visual-studio-2015-cant-sign-in-use-nuget-etc-behind-corporate-proxy).

My final solution was to edit the machine.config file as administrator with Notepad+ in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config` to get ride of the fiddler default proxy definition and to use the system ones:

```
<!--<system.net>
         <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
         <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false"/>
         </defaultProxy>
     </system.net>-->
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Now ASP.Net 5 works fine, I even have my intellisense working properly now which was not the case before with the other proxy definition...

Thanks

Sylvain

Comment: Fiddler was the cause for me, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you installed the latest tooling for [Visual studio](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling). Your project.json seems to be wrong.

Check your nuget feed in visual studio for invalid feed and remove these sources.

Check your active dnx (*)

```
dnvm list
Active Version     Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias

   1.0.0-beta4     clr     x86          win
   1.0.0-beta7     clr     x64          win
   1.0.0-beta7     clr     x86          win             b7
   1.0.0-beta7     coreclr x64          win
   1.0.0-beta7     coreclr x86          win
   1.0.0-beta8     clr     x64          win
*  1.0.0-beta8     clr     x86          win             aa, b8
   1.0.0-beta8     coreclr x64          win
   1.0.0-beta8     coreclr x86          win
   1.0.0-rc1-15838 clr     x86          win             rc1a
   1.0.0-rc1-16031 clr     x86          win             default
   1.0.0-rc1-16031 coreclr x86          win
```

With the `tools->nuget package manager-package manager for solution`
* Select a package source and test if a package source give any errors
* find out in which nuget feed your package is available

At the end of the dnu output there is a list which config and feeds are used

```
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\Thom\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
Feeds used:
 https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
 https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/api/v3/flatcontainer/
```

Use the `dnu restore -?` to find the source of the problem.

try this
`dnu restore --no-cache --packages .\packages1`

Try a package.json like this

```
 {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ClassLibrary3 Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Thom" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "dependencies": {

    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
  },
   "frameworks": {
      "dnx451": { },
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @thom-kiesewetter for pointing me on the tooling page. I followed your instructions, I have beta8 x86 as default, tried the dnu restore (dnu restore --no-cache --packages .\EntityFramework) but still get this error:
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'
Error: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework
  An error occurred while sending the request.

I have also edited my post with my new beta8 project.json and feeds.

Could it be a proxy issue as defined in these discussions: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/451

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the package source was pointing to http://packagesource. Changing it to https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ fixed the probmel