# Asp.Net Core - dnu restore fails on different machine

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, dnu

So, this is working on one computer but when I pull my repository to my laptop I can't restore the packages.

When I run `dnu restore --ignore-failed-sources --no-cache` several packages fail to install:

```
Unable to locate Dependency CommandLineParser >= 1.9.71
Unable to locate Dependency RabbitMQ.Client >= 3.6.1
Unable to locate Dependency AutoMapper >= 4.2.1
Unable to locate Dependency EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design >= 7.0.0-rc1-final
Unable to locate Dependency System.Threading.Timer >= 4.0.1-beta-23516
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS >= 1.0.0-beta7
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener >= 1.0.0-rc1-final
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost >= 1.0.0-rc1-final
Unable to locate Dependency FluentValidation >= 6.2.1
Unable to locate Dependency Faker.Net >= 1.0.3
Unable to locate Dependency Swashbuckle >= 6.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency xunit >= 2.1.0
Unable to locate Dependency xunit.runner.dnx >= 2.1.0-rc1-build204
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client >= 5.2.3
```

and many others.

The feeds I have tried using are:

```
http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json
http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/
```

version:

```
$ dnu --version
Microsoft .NET Development Utility
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16609
 Type:         Clr
 Architecture: x86
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   6.1
 Runtime Id:   win7-x86
```

There are several projects involved, but here is the package.json of the worst one:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "myApp.test Class Library",
  "authors": [ "jcnance" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "david.adapters.glooko": "1.0.0-*",
    "david.mock.glooko": "1.0.0-*",
    "david.core": "1.0.0-*",
    "david.tests": "1.0.0-*",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  }
}
```

Comment: for rc1 you should only be using the nuget.org/v3 one. Your dependencies shows at least one bad reference to a beta7 version. You should post the contents of your project.json so we can see what you have there

Comment: I have tried reducing my source to only v3 but that didn't help. Changing from beta7 to 1.0.0-rc1-final didn't change anything either. I have posted one of my package.json files above

Comment: why do you have Server.IIS which is not the right package or version anyway or even .Server.WebListener if your library is for unit tests?

Comment: I probably copied it off an example I was working from. Removing it doesn't solve the issue though. What I don't understand is why packages like `CommandLineParser`, `RabbitMQ`  and packages that have nothing to do with rc1 can't be found. As you'll notice in the package.json above, the only framework I am supporting right now is dnx451

Comment: I think there is an issue with connectivity. If I run `Install-Package CommandLineParser` on the NuGet command prompt, it installs fine on one machine, but doesn't work on the other throwing `Unable to load the service index for source x`. Exact same project.json, exact same nuget.config files. I just don't know how to fix it. The error is reproducible on every network I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/33405651/2322026

Requests were being proxied through Fiddler and Fiddler wasn't open.